# C++ OpenSSL AES CBC decryption converted to Node.JS does not decrypt correctly. Why?

Tags: c++, node.js, encryption

I'm trying to convert some C++ / Qt decryption code to Node.JS. But unfortunately, it does not decrypt correctly.

I already validated, that the "publicKey" variable has the correct content, also the "iv" and "cipher" are correct. So either there's something with the key import in Node.JS wrong or with the decryption itself. But I can not imagine what. Has someone an idea what could be wrong in my code conversion?

Original C++ code (a bit simplified, I can not post the complete code):

```cpp
AES_KEY *aesKey = new AES_KEY;

AES_set_decrypt_key(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(publicKey.data()), 256, aesKey);

QByteArray iv =  encryptedFile.read(AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

int blocksPerLoop = 10000;

QByteArray cipher = encryptedFile.read(AES_BLOCK_SIZE * (blocksPerLoop + 1));

int sizeOfInput = cipher.size();

unsigned char *content;

content = new unsigned char[sizeOfInput];
memset(content, 0, sizeof(sizeOfInput));

AES_cbc_encrypt(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(cipher.data()),
                content,
                size_t(sizeOfInput),
                aesKey,
                reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(iv.data()),
                AES_DECRYPT);

int paddingLength = content[sizeOfInput - 1];

qDebug() << "paddingLength" << paddingLength; // prints: 16
```

My converted Node.JS code that does not decrypt correctly:

```js
const aesKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex'), { 
    name: 'AES-CBC', 
    length: 256 
}, false, [
    'encrypt', 
    'decrypt'
])

let iv = Buffer.allocUnsafe(AES_BLOCK_SIZE)
await encryptedFile.read(iv, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE)

const blocksPerLoop = 10000

const cipher = Buffer.allocUnsafe(AES_BLOCK_SIZE * (blocksPerLoop + 1))
await encryptedFile.read(cipher, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE * (blocksPerLoop + 1))

const sizeOfInput = cipher.length

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', aesKey, iv)
decipher.setAutoPadding(false)
const content = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(cipher), decipher.final()])

const paddingLength = content[sizeOfInput - 1]

console.log('paddingLength', paddingLength) // prints: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it ... stupid.

seems that's all I need for the key:

```js
const aesKey = publicKey.substring(0, 32)
```

So all this is unnecessary:

```js
const aesKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', Buffer.from(publicKey, 'hex'), { 
    name: 'AES-CBC', 
    length: 256 
}, false, [
    'encrypt', 
    'decrypt'
])
```